# Photoshop JSX Crop: Dcoument too big

Tags: javascript, jsx, photoshop

I'm trying to get a javascript running in photoshop, and one of the functions it needs is a crop, where the coordinates get supplied by a user of a website. I then have the coordinates exported into a XML to use in the JS, and that all works okay. However when I try to make the crop it comes up with a photoshop error saying the resulting document would be too big.

I have pretty limited experience with Photoshop, but after some research it seems like it could have something to do with the resolution being bumped up by a Resample option. However, I can't figure out how to disable this for the JS crop function, simply disabling it under Image.. settings doesn't work.

Here is the part of the code that I use to create the crop, incase it isn't what I stated above:

```
//coordinates comes from the XML file, an example: 1266,0,4058,2792
var bounds = coordinates.split(",");

try { app.activeDocument.crop(bounds); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most operations Photoshop uses units defined in the preferences and by default those are inches. So I imagine it's your case: Photoshop tries to crop document to 2792 inches and chokes. Set units to pixels first (and then optionally restore user's units)

```
var currentUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

app.activeDocument.crop(bounds);

app.preferences.rulerUnits = currentUnits;
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think to check that, it seems to have worked. Thank you!